# RBM - What are visible and hidden biases?

Tags: bias, restricted-boltzmann-machine

Can someone explain to me what is a visible bias and what is a hidden bias in case of a Restricted Boltzmann Machine ? I know what is meant by biases but what is hidden and visible bias ?

Does visible and hidden biases only deal with RBMs or are they applicable for all neural networks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are propagating up from the visible layer to the hidden layer you have the rbm weights plus the bias weights, which in this upwards positive stage are called the hidden biases.

For the downward propagation from the hidden layer, after sampling the hidden layer, to the reconstruction of the visible layer you use the same rbm weights but a different set of bias weights. This second set of bias weights are the visible biases. A quick look at the rbm code at [Geoff Hinton's homepage](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/MatlabForSciencePaper.html) should make this much clearer.